# git highlighting style for listings

Tags: listings, git

Is there a *predefined* highlighting style that I could use with package `listings` so that output from git commands like `git diff`, `git log` can be highlighted as they show up on the terminal (added lines, removed lines, local branches, remote branches, line colors when using `git log --graph`)?

Another possibility would be to be able to bring in colorized terminal output into a document. Are there tricks in that direction? Because if I just copy/paste the output, there will be no formatting.... but would it be possible to include control sequences to change colors and latex would be able to parse it like terminals do? If I pipe a git command with `--color` to force it to be used and pipe into less, I would get this:

```
ESC[33m643baeaESC[m Basics - what is a conflict?
ESC[33m078067aESC[m Conventions
ESC[33mb2b597fESC[m A main file to hold them together
ESC[33mcfc40acESC[m audience and resources
ESC[33mb5121f7ESC[m Introduction
ESC[33m0f367fcESC[m License
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, please give a Minimum Working Example (MWE): [How to make a “minimum example”](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything in the language definitions that come with the main package (cf. http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/lstdrvrs.pdf). I'd have suggested `minted` (based on Python's `pygmentize`), but I couldn't see anything useful there either (https://pygments.org/languages/).